# DAX consolidated running balance from two fact tables

Tags: dax, cumulative-sum, running-balance

I have this simple data model w/ two fact tables that pertain to purchases and sales of shares of stock:
[image]

I need to calculate a running balance by taking a running sum of shares purchased by ticker and SUBTRACT by the running sum of shares sold by ticker.

I tried this:

```
Shares balance 1 = 
VAR Date_Ref = MAX( dDates[Date] )
VAR Tick_Ref = VALUES( dAssets[Ticker] )
VAR Cumm_Purch = 
    CALCULATE( 
        SUMX( 
            fPurch, 
            fPurch[Shares] 
        ), 
        fPurch[Ticker] = Tick_Ref, 
        fPurch[Date] <= Date_Ref 
    )
VAR Cumm_Sold = 
    CALCULATE( 
        SUMX( 
            fSales, 
            fSales[Shares] 
        ), 
        fSales[Ticker] = Tick_Ref, 
        fSales[Date] <= Date_Ref 
    )
VAR Result = Cumm_Purch - Cumm_Sold
RETURN
    Result
```

And I also tried this:

```
Shares balance 2 = 
VAR Date_Ref_Purch = MAX( fPurch[Date] )
VAR Tick_Ref_Purch = VALUES( fPurch[Ticker] )
VAR Cumm_Purch = 
    CALCULATE( 
        SUMX( 
            fPurch, 
            fPurch[Shares] 
        ), 
        fPurch[Ticker] = Tick_Ref_Purch, 
        fPurch[Date] <= Date_Ref_Purch 
    )
VAR Date_Ref_Sold = MAX( fSales[Date] )
VAR Tick_Ref_Sold = VALUES( fSales[Ticker] )
VAR Cumm_Sold = 
    CALCULATE( 
        SUMX( 
            fSales, 
            fSales[Shares] 
        ), 
        fSales[Ticker] = Tick_Ref_Sold, 
        fSales[Date] <= Date_Ref_Sold 
    )
VAR Result = Cumm_Purch - Cumm_Sold
RETURN
    Result
```

And both produce the same WRONG results, as shown on the sample table that follows...

For this visual the 'Ticker' column comes from the dimension table dAssets and the 'Date' column comes from the date table.

And the 'Correct result' column I manually added to show the numbers I was supposed to compute:

| Ticker | Date | Shares purchased | Shares sold | Shares balance 1 | Shares balance 2 | Correct result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABEV | 3/1/2021 | 77 |  | 77 | 77 | **77** |
| ABEV | 5/4/2021 | 73 |  | 73 | 73 | **150** |
| ABEV | 6/4/2021 |  | 150 | -150 | -150 | **0** |
| ABEV | 6/28/2021 | 62 |  | 62 | 62 | **62** |
| ABEV | 10/29/2021 |  | 62 | -62 | -62 | **0** |
| ALSO3 | 1/7/2021 | 39 |  | 39 | 39 | **39** |
| ALSO3 | 2/3/2021 |  | 39 | -39 | -39 | **0** |
| ALSO3 | 3/1/2021 | 45 |  | 45 | 45 | **45** |
| ALSO3 | 5/11/2021 |  | 45 | -45 | -45 | **0** |
| ALSO3 | 6/29/2021 | 36 |  | 36 | 36 | **36** |
| ALSO3 | 1/7/2022 | 56 |  | 56 | 56 | **92** |
| ALSO3 | 3/30/2022 |  | 92 | -92 | -92 | **0** |

I suppose something on either code is messing up the results, what could that be?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from an user in another forum...

```
Shares purchased = 
VAR Tick_Ref = VALUES( fPurch[Ticker] )
VAR Result = 
    CALCULATE( 
        SUMX( 
            fPurch, 
            fPurch[Shares] 
        ), 
        fPurch[Ticker] = Tick_Ref 
    )
RETURN
    Result

Shares sold = 
VAR Tick_Ref = VALUES( fSales[Ticker] )
VAR Result = 
    CALCULATE( 
        SUMX( 
            fSales, 
            fSales[Shares] 
        ), 
        fSales[Ticker] = Tick_Ref 
    )
RETURN
    Result

Shares balance = 
VAR Tick_Ref = VALUES( dAssets[Ticker] )
VAR Date_Ref = MAX( dDates[Date] )
VAR Acumm_Purch = 
    CALCULATE( 
        SUM( fPurch[Shares] ), 
        dAssets[Ticker] = Tick_Ref, 
        dDates[Date] <= Date_Ref 
    )
VAR Acumm_Sold = 
    CALCULATE( 
        SUM( fSales[Shares] ), 
        dAssets[Ticker] = Tick_Ref, 
        dDates[Date] <= Date_Ref 
    )
VAR Result = 
    IF( 
        [Shares purchased] <> BLANK() || 
        [Shares sold] <> BLANK(), 
        Acumm_Purch - Acumm_Sold 
    )
RETURN
    Result
```